# Spring-Thymeleaf - Form Validation Not Working

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm creating a form with validation with Spring MVC & Thymeleaf on my html. The point is, my validation isn't working & the page gives me "**This page isn't working HTTP ERROR 400**".

Here's my Controller:

```
@Autowired
ChannelService channelService;

@Autowired
RuleService ruleService;

@GetMapping("/config/{channelCode}/form/create")
public String createForm(@PathVariable String channelCode, Authentication authentication, ModelMap model) {     
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
    ChannelDto channelDto = channelService.findByClientIdAndChannelCode(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId(), channelCode);
    model.addAttribute("channel", channelDto);
    if (!model.containsAttribute("createForm")) {
        model.addAttribute("createForm", new StoreDto());
    }
    return "configuration/sales_channel_create";
}
    
@RequestMapping(value="/config/{channelCode}/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postForm(
    @Valid @ModelAttribute("createForm") StoreDto form, @PathVariable String channelCode, Authentication  authentication, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        
    try {
        form.setClientId(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId());
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.createRuleSettingForm", result);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("createForm", form);
            return "redirect:/config/"+form.getChannelCode()+"/form/create";
        }
        ruleService.save(form);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("err", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("createForm", form);
        return "redirect:/config/"+form.getChannelCode()+"/form/create";
    }
    return "redirect:/config/"+form.getChannelCode()+"/view/STORE_CODE";
}
```

Here are my validation (there's only one right now because I'm still testing):

```
private Long id;
private Long clientId;
private String channelCode;
private String storeCode;
@Size(min=5, max=50, message="Store Name length should be between 5 to 50")
private String storeName;
private String storeProvince;
private String storeCity;
private String storeDistrict;
private String storeAddress;
private String storePhone;
private String courierName;
private boolean isActive=false;
```

What's inside my ruleService.save():

```
public boolean save(StoreDto storeDto) {
    ProviderStore rulesStore = new ProviderStore();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(storeDto, rulesStore);
    rulesStore.setId(storeDto.getId());
    rulesStore.setActive(storeDto.isActive());
    storeRepository.save(rulesStore);
    return true;
}
```

Here's my sales_channel_create.html (note, there's only one th:if right now because I'm still testing):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
    th:replace="~{fragments/layout :: layout (~{::body},'salesChannel')}">

<body>
    <div class="page-title">
        <div class="title_left">
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- Bread crumb and right sidebar toggle -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <div class="row page-titles">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 align-self-center">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item">Configuration</li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a th:href="@{/config}">Channel</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item">Rules Setting</li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Create</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- End Bread crumb and right sidebar toggle -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm- col-xs-3"></div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Create a New Store Code</h2>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">
                    <br />
                    <form id="demo-form2" th:action="@{|/config/${channel.channelCode}/create|}" th:object="${createForm}" method="post" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                <input type="hidden" id="channelCode" name="channelCode" th:value="${channel.channelCode}" readonly>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="code">Code <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="code" name="storeCode" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" th:value="*{storeCode}">
                        </div> 
                      </div>
                      <div style="color: red; text-align: center">
                        <p th:if="${err}">Store Code already exist</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Name <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="name" name="storeName" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" th:field="*{storeName}" th:value="*{storeName}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div style="color: red; text-align: center">
                        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('storeName')}" th:errors="*{storeName}"></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="courier">Courier <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="courier" name="courierName" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" th:value="*{courierName}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="province">Province <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="province" name="storeProvince" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" th:value="*{storeProvince}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="city">City <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="city" name="storeCity" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" th:value="*{storeCity}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="district">District <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="district" name="storeDistrict" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" th:value="*{storeDistrict}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="address">Address <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="address" name="storeAddress" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" th:value="*{storeAddress}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="phone">Phone <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="phone" name="storePhone" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" th:value="*{storePhone}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="active">Active </label>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="active" name="active" th:checked="*{active}">
                            <label>Yes</label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Reset</button>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Is there's anything wrong with my codes? Again, it's not working & the gives me **HTTP ERROR 400**.

Comment: when are you getting the error 400? when loading the page itself? or when doing the save operation?

Comment: When I submit invalid input

Comment: You’ve `@Size` constraint in your DTO and then `@Valid` in your controller method. So, when it’s invalid, it will produce 400.

Comment: I actually just found the problem & solved it, I literally put BindingResult parameter not right after ModelAttribute parameter in my controller & when I repositioned my BindingResult parameter right after ModelAttribute parameter, it worked as intended. Parameter order really that matter huh... -_-